# HTML Option tag with selected value from PHP

Tags: php, html

Can you please help me out as to what I am doing wrong with this code:

```
<option value="">------------ Select ------------</option>
<?php while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($tech))) {
                            ?>
<option value= <?php echo $row['id'] ?> 
<?php echo $selectedtechname ?>
<?php echo "selected" ?>
                          >
 <?php echo $row['technician_name'] ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
```

All variables are working fine since I used Var_dump and they echo correctly so no errors is SQL etc. What I need to do is pass a php statement in the option tag of HTML to simply select the value of $selectedtechname from the list. The value to post is $row['id'] but the selected value to show should be $selectedtechname

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you are missing the closing curly bracket for the while loop.

Comment: What option should be "selected"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP MySQL Drop Down Box Populate Selected Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725263/php-mysql-drop-down-box-populate-selected-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a similar post
[populate a select box with php mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895035/populate-a-select-box-with-php-mysql)

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   if ($row['technician_name'] == $selectedtechname) {
       echo '<option   value=\"'.$row['id'].'" selected>'.$row['id'].'</option>';
   } else {
       echo '<option   value=\"'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['id'].'</option>';
   }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP needs `if ($row['technician_name'] == $selectedtechname)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
 $selected='';
    <option value="">Select a value</option>
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($tech)) {
    ?>
       <?php
         if($selectedtechname == $row['selectedtechname'])
          {
             $selected='selected';
          }
          else
          {
            $selected='';
          }
        ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']?>" <?php echo $selected;?> ><?php echo $row['value_to_display'];?></option>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: How do you know OP has `$row['selectedtechname']` as database field name?

Comment: assuming that. bcoz he did not mentioned it.

Comment: then consider using `if ($row['id'] == $selectedtechname) {` possibly OP needs this.

Comment: I would stay with `if($selectedtechname == $row['selectedtechname'])` as that seems the most logical, give the OPs code.

Comment: May be.. @ OP I do not know by $selectedtechname what you are matching then use correspondin in $row['your_corresponding_field']